# Rpm package information: Auto incrementing version

Tags: rpmbuild

I wondering if any one knew if there was a way to auto increment the Version/Release number for the information found in an rpm package.

i.e.

> rpm -qil 'package_name'

Would return something like:

```
Name: package_name
Version: 1.5
Release: 000001
```

Is there a way to auto increment the release number every time i perform an rpmbuild? The rpm information is located in a spec file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind having epoch as a release number, you could do this:

```
Release: 0.%(perl -e 'print time()')
```

The reason I put 0. in front is so if you want to ever use something other than epoch as the release tag, and not change the version, you can.

Comment: Is there any way to change the version number only

Comment: I don't understand your question here.

Comment: I have Installed a RPM package using rpm -i command, when i query rpm -q it shows me the version what i described in the spec file, now i want change the version number alone, without affecting any file, how can i perform this,

Comment: Just change the version number in the spec file and rebuild it.

Comment: it should be rpm -i or rpm -U option, when i do rpm -U it uninstall the previous version and install the new one, that need to avoided

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add to your makefile something like:

```
perl -i.`date +"%s"` -pe 'if (/^Release:/) { s#(\d+)#$1+1#e }' YOURSPECFILE.spec
```

Every time this oneliner is run, it increments the integer found in the row beginning with "Release:".

The operation is done in-place and for safety reasons the previous contents of the SPEC file is saved in a backup file with the epoch number attached to the filename. You may also use something like "-i.BAK" if you need only one backup or simply "-i" if you are sure that nothing wrong ever happens.

Answer (score -1):

you can also set and ENV Variable like so:

```
export RPM_VERSION=1.1.1
```

and then use perl to grab it:

```
perl -e 'print $ENV{RPM_VERSION}'
```

This is what I'm about to use when building RPMs in Bamboo.

Comment: You know environment variables are available in bash as well - just do $(echo $RPM_VERSION) and you don't have to invoke perl